# Vue.js transition doesn't apply on page first load

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a navbar with links that switch between two components.
I've got a fade-in animation for the switching, but it wouldn't run when you first open the page (it runs only when you use the navbar links to switch the components).
Is there any way to overcome this?

P.S. The components are just `<h1>Home</h1>` and `<h1>About</h1>`.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="app">
  <transition name="view">
      <router-view/>
  </transition>
</div>
```

**JS (Router):**

```
Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: { name: 'home-route' }
    },
    {
      path: '/home',
      name: 'home-route',
      component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about-route',
      component: AboutComponent
    }
  ]
})
```

**CSS (Animation):**

```
.view-leave-active {
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out, transform 0.5s ease;
}

.view-enter-active {
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out, transform 0.5s ease;
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.view-enter, .view-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
}

.view-enter-to, .view-leave {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

View transitions don't automatically work on page load as when the content is loaded they haven't been initialised yet.

You have to find another way to trigger the transition. I can think of a few options.

1. Hide the component by default with a data prop and then in the `mounted` life cycle switch it to true. This should trigger the transition.

```html
<div v-if="show"></div>
```

```js
data() {
    return {
      show: false
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.show = true; // might need this.$nextTick
  }
```

2. Use a regular css transition.

Similar to the above approach, give the parent element a class with a style

```css
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
```

Then on `mount` add a class to change the opacity to 1.

Comment: sir how to add styling when the component mounted?

Answer (score 27):

Just add "appear" attribute in the transition wrapper.
And you will need your css classes for the animtaion or transition to.
Example:

```
<transition name="fade" appear></transition>
```

Comment: that would be great :)

Comment: What do you mean by "And you will need your css classes for the animtaion or transition to."?

Comment: that means the kind of transition you will show. for example, you want to do opacity transition from 0 to 1. if transition starts, opacity is zero and then, if transition time that you set is over, the opacity is set to 1 automaticly. here the example: 

opacity .fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
}

Comment: appear does not work on initial page load (when using SSR).

Comment: This worked for me. Can't believe I missed this in the transition documentation. Thanks!

Comment: @DrewBaker did you use nuxt? Try <client-only></client-only> tag.

Comment: two houres pure frustration and I just read this part. You saved my laptop